# Protect HTTP-triggered Azure Function (Python) from malicious executions

Tags: python, azure-functions, brute-force, ddos

Is there any protection to put in place to prevent an HTTP-triggered Azure Function (Python runtime) from being maliciously triggered?

I have HTTPS and Client-certificates-required enabled.

Endpoint must be exposed to internet to allow for external clients to access. Concern is that "someone" will find the endpoint and attempt DDOS or brute force attacks. I want to protect the function from executing each time (even though it will fail).

Any ideas? Or am I worrying about something that doesn't matter? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could enable DDoS Protections associated with functions app and can take care of the same. This is service provided to protect your azure services (The basic protection is of no cost)

[image]

Comparison between Basic vs Standard :

[image]

For detailed steps you could refer the below link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/manage-ddos-protection
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/security-concepts

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, after review of the docs and setup of a test, this only protects Azure Functions on a VNET. What about stand-alone HTTP-triggered functions that are not on a VNET?